# Datetime field getting null when data pass angularjs to controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I want to save date and time field to db.On below code when Pass model js to controller the field `PickupDateAndtime` getting as null.But in js has value.
what is the wrong in this code

```
<tr ng-repeat="data in lstdata>
<td><input type="text" style="width: 130px;" class="form-control mydatepicker " ng-model="data.PickupDateAndtime" data-date-format="dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm:ss"></td>
</tr>
$scope.Save= function () {
    $http({
        method: "post",
        url: "/api/home/Save",
        data: JSON.stringify($scope.lstdata)
    }).then(function (response) {

    });
}
public class details
{
public long Id { get; set; }
public DateTime? PickupDateAndtime { get; set; }
}

[Route("Save")]
[HttpPost]
public string Save(IEnumerable<details> Det)
{    
  foreach (var d in Det
  {
   int res = this.dbEntity.SAVESTOREDPROC(
    Convert.ToInt32(d.Id) ,                       
    d.PickupDateAndtime
    );
  }    
   return "0";            
}
```

Here how can get formatted Datetime

Comment: are you getting data JSON.stringify($scope.lstdata)??

Comment: yes.In controller `Id` field has value.but `PickupDateAndtime` as null

Comment: can you share the data passed to server on click of save?

Comment: Why are you using stringyfy?  I never use that when passing to MVC Controller.

Answer (score 0):

Check what data is passed to server when you call the save function (from browser network tab).
The date picker might be putting some value which can't be parsed to C# datetime by mvc model binder.

Comment: In controller.js, the date as in `27-07-2017 04:00:00` format.Get in controller as `null`